# MySQL Query (database) - trying to display only certain values

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello there i am having little problem. I have two tables in my database.
[image]

As you can see i am getting all employees in one tab, and what i am trying to achieve here is to display only relevant employees in given tab. So employees from Customer services wont be displayed in Sales tab for example.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * "."FROM employees, dept_emp "."WHERE employees.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no");
```

Thank you for looking and help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your WHERE clause is useless as it is just restating a JOIN condition basically. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees AS e
INNER JOIN dept_emp AS de ON e.emp_no = de.emp_no
WHERE de.dept_no = '?'
```

Obviously the `?` would be substituted with the `dept_no` value you are actually trying to filter on.

Per your question about seeting query limits/pagination, that is done via SQL `LIMIT` clause.  The clause can be expressed in a few different ways.

This first just returns a max number of rows:

```
LIMIT 100 <-- shows first 100 rows from the result set
```

The following two forms of syntax are used for pagination of results:

```
LIMIT 0, 100 <-- show first 100 rows from the result set (start at 0 offset, and return a max of 100 rows
LIMIT 100, 100 <-- show rows 101-200 from the result set (start at 100 offset and return max of 100 rows)
```

Or:

```
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0 <-- first 100 rows
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100 <-- rows 101-200
```

So putting it all together

```
SELECT *
FROM employees AS e
INNER JOIN dept_emp AS de ON e.emp_no = de.emp_no
WHERE de.dept_no = '?'
ORDER BY e.emp_no
LIMIT 0,100
```

Note that I also added an `ORDER BY` clause.  This is important for pagination in that just a regular unordered `SELECT` doesn't guarantee order.  If you tried to paginate without an `ORDER BY` you could potentially get the same row returned in multiple "pages".

Comment: Thank you for help here, if you could also tell me how to limit number of results lets say to a 100, and rest will be showed on next pages. Reason why im asking this is because i have database with almost 300k entries, so when i will try to load even one department with more then few k people it wont do any good.

Comment: @MaciejCygan Pagination is done via use of the `LIMIT` clause.  Please see my updated answer for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear you are limiting the departments.  The where clause needs a hard limit, your where will always match everything. Also, why are you concatenating your statement? It doesn't break. 
Something like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees JOIN dept_emp ON employees.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no WHERE dept_emp.dept_no = 'd007'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dept = ?;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *
                     FROM employees, dept_emp 
                     WHERE employees.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no  
                           AND de.dept_no = $dept 
         ");
```